# I am new to CAPL and looking for its tutorials

Tags: capl, canoe

Is there any data available regarding CAPL

-Books

- Tutorial
- Channels etc ,.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.academia.edu/34469538/Quick_Introduction_To_CAPL
This application note is a brief introduction to CAPL, the easy-to-use C-based programming language and integrated programming environment inside both CANalyzer and CANoe.